# Coalesce Function in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I am using IBM DB2. I have a query which gives the output as:

### NAME         /               AMOUNT

CST  /                    -

VAT  / 1400

ST   /  -

I am trying to write a coalesce function for AMOUNT. The datatype of AMOUNT is decimal(10,2)

```
COALESCE(AMOUNT,'&nbsp')
```

The purpose of me doing is, I want a space if the AMOUNT is null, but all I get is an error like "incompatible argument".

How can I achieve a space? Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are saying this...

If amount is not NULL, display a decimal value, but if it is, display a character value instead.   Try this

```
COALESCE(CAST(AMOUNT as VARCHAR(20)),'&nbsp;')
```

Should solve your problem